# Parse a String to a Date using Date.ParseStrategy

Tags: swift, date, parsing

I would like to parse a `06/19/2022 01:00 PDT` date.

Using a new `Date.ParseStrategy(format:)` i wrote this:

```swift
import Foundation


let dateFromNetwork = "06/19/2022 01:00 PDT"

let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "\(month: .twoDigits)/\(day: .twoDigits)/\(year: .defaultDigits) \(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twelveHour, hourCycle: .zeroBased)):\(minute: .twoDigits)", timeZone: .init(abbreviation: "PDT")!)

let date = try! Date(dateFromNetwork, strategy: strategy)
// Cannot parse 06/19/2022 01:00 PDT
// String should ahere to specified format, such as 06/20/2022 01:00
```

How to deal with latest part of timezone `PDT`?

Comment: can you try with `let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "\(month: .twoDigits)/\(day: .twoDigits)/\(year: .defaultDigits) \(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twelveHour, hourCycle: .zeroBased)):\(minute: .twoDigits) PDT", locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX"), timeZone: .current)`

Comment: Damn! This working.
Can you answer?

Comment: So the strings you want to parse always has PDT as the time zone?

Comment: Great question. Time zone depends on the geolocation. When geo is matched, i’ve got the time zone: GMT, PDT, etc. If time zone GMT — string be `"12.06.2022 17:58 GMT"`

Comment: So basically the time zone is dynamic and using a hardcoded one as in the accepted answer will not really work?

Comment: At this point it works. I haven't gotten to testing with another time zone.

Comment: @wmorgue as from your previous comment `When geo is matched, i’ve got the time zone: GMT, PDT, etc. If time zone GMT — string be "12.06.2022 17:58 GMT"` you have to make dynamic ParseStrategy like to get timezone abbreviation and date separator((/ - Slash) or (. - Dot)) from input format right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this strategy:

```
let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "(month: .twoDigits)/(day: .twoDigits)/(year: .defaultDigits) (hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twelveHour, hourCycle: .zeroBased)):(minute: .twoDigits) PDT", timeZone: .init(abbreviation: "PDT")!)
```

In your case, You're not using `timeZone` in your format.

Comment: Cannot parse. String should adhere to spec format, such as 
`06/19/2022 01:00 Los Angeles`

Comment: This is what I was afraid of, . genericLocation is not what you need in this case. Maybe try this: .identifier(.short)

Comment: with `.identifier(.short)`: 
Cannot parse. String should adhere to spec format, such as  `06/19/2022 01:00 uslax`. Hm 

Comment: I Apologize, after some serious trial and error I found this let strategy = Date.ParseStrategy(format: "\(month: .twoDigits)/\(day: .twoDigits)/\(year: .defaultDigits) \(hour: .twoDigits(clock: .twelveHour, hourCycle: .zeroBased)):\(minute: .twoDigits) PDT",  timeZone: .init(abbreviation: "PDT")!)

Comment: Great. This also work.

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it resolved your problem, Thanks